# T-SQL Getting the coulmn names for a view from a UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a view involving quite a few UNIONs and a fair number of columns. For brevity I want to define the column list once and then re-use it multiple times in the T-SQL for the view. It being a view, I can't declare local variables.

So I have a UDF **fnGetColumnList** taking no params that returns nvarchar(max) containing the list of fields, i.e. '[field1] as [Field 1], [field2] as [Field 2]' and so on. That works fine.

What I can't figure out is if it is possible to use that as the column list when creating the view. For example this doesn't work.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myView]
AS

SELECT [dbo].[fnGetColumnList] from [dbo].[table]

GO
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: No, you can't use it like that in a view, since it would need dynamic SQL. Also, it would be a terrible idea to do that anyway, since the only justification is if the list is not static, which doesn't make sense for a view

Comment: You could possibly make use of CTEs and `SELECT *` on them, if your only goal is to save typing. When used on CTEs, `SELECT *` is slightly less evil than in general, since you are in full control of the number of columns and their order. Even so, you'll find that T-SQL does not care about brevity, but it does care a lot about having statically typed result sets.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I like this sentence *you'll find that T-SQL does not care about brevity* ;-D

Comment: T-SQL might not, but I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I can't figure out is if it is possible to use that as the column
>   list when creating the view.

Literally, yes, this is possible.  You would have to use dynamic SQL to create the view.

Can you have this **IN** your view?   No.  You cannot use dynamic SQL **IN** the code of a view.   But you can use it to CREATE the view:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql='
 CREATE VIEW dbo.MyViewName
 AS 
 SELECT ' + dbo.MyFunction + '
 ...
';
EXECUTE (@sql);
```